# How to make a text with smaller width stay on a image with 100% width even if the screen is resized?

Tags: html, css

How to make a text with smaller width stay on a image with 100% width even if the screen is resized? I want that the text stays on the background. At the moment the text goes outside of the image when I make the screensize smaller I tried everything and I can't find a good solution for it. Please help!

HTML(Ruby on Rails)

```
<div class="outer-wrapper">
 <%= image_tag("x.png" class="background") %>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
   <p> Feel free to reach out to me with anything that’s on your mind. I’m always
   happy to hear from people and I’ll respond as quickly as possible. </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS Part

```
.outer-wrapper {
}

.background {
min-width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
height: 900px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
width: 41%;
height: 100%;
margin: 2% auto;
left: 0; 
right: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 172%;
}
```

Comment: Add `position:relative;` to your outer wrapper. This is because your `inner-wrapper` uses `position:absolute`, so it's parent needs to be relative ...

Comment: I tried that the content disappears which should be on the background :/

Comment: Add `width:100%;` to your `outer-wrapper` ... And `height:auto;overflow:auto;`

Comment: I get an SyntaxError Message "Invalid CSS after " height": expected ";", was ": auto;" :/
The "height: auto;" and "overflow: auto;"  are given me the error messages. I tried bouth separately as well.

Comment: Change the `top` value to something less than 100%

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ay9f2ud5/

Comment: That syntax error, you are most likely missing a `;` on the previous line

Comment: You are right I really missed a ; ! Thanks allot you helped me allot can u suggest me a book or a source where I can learn more about divs in relation of layout? Thanks again!

Comment: To be honest, I learned everything I know from the StackExchange network (Or Googling) ... I took the 'trial and error' approach ... Which is probably how I got so good at troubleshooting Lol ... I usually take an hour or two out of my day to try answering other peoples questions. Chances are, if they have a problem, you will run into it one day.